# C - Simple Stars Triangle

Tags: c

I would like to produce pattern like this

n=5

```
xyoyx
xyoy
xyo
xy
X
```

n=6

```
xyoyxy
xyoyx
xyoy
xyo
xy
x
```

Thank you

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Comment: Deja-vu.  It's a homework dump:(    The rest of the class wil be along shortly...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43237992/7761980

Comment: I'll happily wrote the code for you, and even turn it in! I just need your professor's name and email, so I can save him the trouble of Googling your code and directly tell him you're attempting to commit academic dishonesty, which will at the very least earn you an F in the class, and depending on if you continue to try to get through college by using other people's work, will get you expelled, too.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void) {
    int i , j ,n;
    printf("n=");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("\n");

    for(i = n-1; i >=0 ; i--) 
    {
            for(j = 0; j <= i; j++)
            {
                if(j%4==0)
                   printf("x");
                else if(j%4==2)
                   printf("o");
                else if(j%2==1)
                   printf("y");

            }
            printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;

}
```